ModalBottomSheet not respecting navigation padding
Trying to show a simple ModalBottomSheet and struggling with both the navigation and status bar padding. There's not a way to have the content sit above the nav buttons on some devices. It seems to work on a Pixel 6, but 3a seems to ignore it (see images below).
 ModalBottomSheet(
        modifier = Modifier,
        containerColor = Colors.Grey,
        sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(true),
        content = {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .navigationBarsPadding(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                Text(text = "Some text at the bottom", color = Color.Black)
            }
}

This is added as a ComposeView to the Activity's content view.
 viewGroup.addView(
        ComposeView(viewGroup.context).apply {
            setContent {
                AppTheme {
                    // Modal Bottom sheet above
                }
            }
        }
    )

where viewGroup is activity.findViewById(R.id.content) as ViewGroup to support interop
Any suggestion on how to add bottom padding to match the nav button height? Or other suggestions to have the bottom sheet not obscure the buttons? Also, the same thing with status bar.


There is an issue on the Google Issue Tracker that seems similar to what you are experiencing. The Android Team is aiming to migrate the ModalBottomSheet to use a Dialog under the hood, as described in this commit. However, it seems that the work is still in progress.
You can however try out the latest version of the material3 dependency and check whether some changes have already been published there:
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.3.0-alpha04"

Also note that there is a dedicated windowInsets parameter available in ModalBottomSheet, once the underlying issue is fixed, you can use that to customize the behavior.
@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
fun ModalBottomSheet(
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    // ...
    windowInsets: WindowInsets = BottomSheetDefaults.windowInsets,
    // ...
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit
): Unit


None of those work for me, except safeContentPadding. It seems to add tons of top padding that's even well below the status bar. Not sure why none of these are working.

It might be a bug in Compose, I edited my answer.

I was having for the issue for android 10 or bellow, i just add an extra WindowInsets to fix the issue.
My code:
ModalBottomSheet(
    onDismissRequest = {
        controller.hide()
        onDismiss?.invoke()
    },
    sheetState = sheetState,
    windowInsets = WindowInsets.systemBars
        .only(WindowInsetsSides.Bottom).run {
            if (needsImeInsets) {
                union(WindowInsets.ime)
            } else {
                this
            }
        }
) {
    content()
}

// Android 10 or bellows needs the ime padding
// To prevent EditTexts to be covered by the keyboard
private val needsImeInsets = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q

